# Threads problems on android. help please

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I have a `button`. In the `onclick` event, want to run one `progressDialog`, and then, while is loading `progressDialog`, run an `AsyncTask`.

My code:

Method OnCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

principal_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.principal_layout);
text_search = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
search_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
input_song = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

search_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Working..", "Loading, please wait..", true, false);
                }
            });

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

    }});
}
```

Method handler (var Handler)

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        if(msg.what == 1){
            try {
                songs = new AsyncTasks().new GetSong(MainActivity.this).execute("mySong","1").get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
        else if(msg.what == 0){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Finished process", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(pd != null && pd.isShowing()){
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

};

The code does not generate any errors, but next is a follows:

When I click on the button, the program executes the following line:

**songs = new AsyncTasks().new GetSong(MainActivity.this).execute("mySong","1").get();**

, and once it finishes running, then recently there progressDialog shows. My hope is that it shows the exact moment to click on the button (without delay).

Comment: onClick already runs on the UI thread, so you don't need to use runOnUiThread. Also, you don't need to use a Handler in this case: just create and start the AsyncTask in the onClick method. Unrelated: try to choose a title for your question so that people having the same problem can search for it easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simple and clear:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Working..", "Loading, please wait..", true, false);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Loading code
                h.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
});
```

Comment: This works. The only down side is that you suffer the additional overhead of having to recreate a new thread each time you execute the asynchronous task. `AsyncTask` uses a thread pool to execute its tasks so it might be a better choice if, for example, you expect the user to click the button and fire up the task many times.